# Datatype of SUM result in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sum, return-type

I'm having a bit of a problem with converting the result of a MySQL query to a Java class when using SUM.

When performing a simple SUM in MySQL

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM cakes WHERE ingredient = 'chocolate';
```

with `price` being an integer, it appears that the `SUM` sometimes returns a string and sometimes an integer, depending on the version of the JDBC driver.

Apparently the server does tell the JDBC driver that the result of `SUM` is a string, and the JDBC driver sometimes 'conveniently' converts this to an integer. (see [Marc Matthews' explanation](http://marc.info/?l=mysql-java&m=116295785422117&w=2)).

The Java code uses some [BeanInfo](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) and [Introspection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) to automagically fill in a (list of) bean(s) with the result of a query. But this obviously can't work if the datatypes differ between servers where the application is deployed.

I don't care wether I get a string or an integer, but I'd like to always have the same datatype, or at least know in advance which datatype I'll be getting.

Is there some way to know which datatype will be returned by a MySQL `SUM` from within the Java code? Or does anyone know some better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just a guess, but maybe casting to integer will force MySQL to always tell it is an integer.

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(price) AS SIGNED) FROM cakes WHERE ingredient = 'marshmallows';
```

Comment: what's with the marshmallows ?

Comment: I like cakes with marshmallows

Comment: So focused on fiddling with the driver I completely overlooked the bleeding obvious mysql workaround :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Okay, this answer&comments just started to stroll around the internet. Noticed it at a random funny picture site.

Comment: @Dykam: That site is probably not very funny, then.

Comment: The fun-level isn't very high indeed, but this made me smile.

Answer (score 2):

I have never worked with MySQL before so I cannot say why but If you say:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SUM(price) FROM cakes WHERE ingredient = 'chocolate'");
int sum = 0;
if(rs.next())
size = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
```

Then you should not have a problem regardless of the returned datatype as the documentation says:

> #### String getString(int  columnIndex) throws SQLException
>
> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object **as a String** in the Java programming language

Comment: With java 11 and mysql connector j 8 `ResultSet#getString` for a sum of` BIGINTt returns a String with a decimal point i.e. "0. thereforcannot be parsed with `parseInt`

Answer (score -1):

I found `COALESCE(SUM(price),0)` good for always ensuring the field returned 0 if there was no result.

See: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/177427