# How to deal with silent mysql sum() integer overflow?

Tags: sql, mysql, overflow, sum

I've got this table with an `int(11)` column and hundreds of millions of rows.  When I run a query like

```
SELECT SUM(myIntColumn) as foo FROM myTable;
```

the return value does not make sense--it is smaller than the the single largest max value.  My values for this column max out somewhere around 500m, and the signed int should be able to handle ~2bil, so I assume mysql is experiencing an integer overflow, and keeping mum about it.

What to do?

*Miscellaneous details that might just matter but probably not:*

- `mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.75, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`
- `mysqld  Ver 5.0.75-0ubuntu10 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`
- `Linux kona 2.6.28-11-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 17 02:45:36 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: this link help ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323294/datatype-of-sum-result-in-mysql

Comment: I saw that, but the question seemed non-trivially different because of the integer/string behavior the poster was asking about.  My MySql is not deep enough to understand these types of subtleties.  And my database so large that interactive experimentation is not possible...some queries of mine have taken hours!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can double the range by casting the value to an unsigned value:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(myIntColumn AS UNSIGNED)) ...
```

There is a bigger data type: the BIGINT, but unfortunately you cannot [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) to it. If you want to make use of it, you must change your column to that type:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable CHANGE COLUMN myIntColumn myBigIntColumn BIGINT UNSIGNED ...
```

Comment: I had to alter the table: Query OK, 327995915 rows affected (29 min 0.12 sec)...cwazy!  Thanks.

Comment: I had the same issue, inverting the cast worked for me: SELECT CAST (SUM(myIntColumn) AS USIGNED) ...