# What is the return type of SUM() in mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing a program in C#.NET
I would like to gather the total frequency of a class (let imagine every class has many words and each word has its own frequency in the corresponding class)

So i used the sum() function in mysql. But there is an error saying that my cast is wrong.

```
 public void average_each_type()
        {
            MySqlDataReader result;
            int total_freq = 0;
            string type = "";

            command.CommandText = "select class_name ,SUM(frequency) as sum_of_freq from training_set group by class_name ";


                result = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (result.Read())
                {

                    total_freq = (int)result["sum_of_freq"]; //error happened here
                    type = result["class_name"].ToString();
                    //.....then so on...//
```

Comment: Should be the same type as the expression; namely, the data type of `frequency` in your database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Datatype of SUM result in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323294/datatype-of-sum-result-in-mysql)

Comment: @JoelEtherton: not exactly a duplicate. Some of the information may be useful though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SUM in MySql will return a decimal or double value, depending on the type within "frequency".  From the [documentation for SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

> The SUM() and AVG() functions return a DECIMAL value for exact-value arguments (integer or DECIMAL), and a DOUBLE value for approximate-value arguments (FLOAT or DOUBLE). (Before MySQL 5.0.3, SUM() and AVG() return DOUBLE for all numeric arguments.)

If you want an integer, you can use `Convert` to get one no matter what the source type happens to be:

```
total_freq = Convert.ToInt32(result["sum_of_freq"]);
```

The advantage here is the [Convert.ToInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz) will work no matter what type of value is returned from the database, provided it is a numeric type.

Answer (score 6):

In Addition to what Reed said, you can also do the integer cast in SQL:

```
CAST(SUM(frequency) as INT) as sum_of_freq
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Can't cast to INT, need to cast to UNSIGNED. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8895978/792203

Answer (score 0):

The SUM() and AVG() functions return a DECIMAL value for exact-value arguments (integer or DECIMAL), and a DOUBLE value for approximate-value arguments (FLOAT or DOUBLE). (Before MySQL 5.0.3, SUM() and AVG() return DOUBLE for all numeric arguments.)