# how to convert BigDecimal to integer in MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

when running query like:

```
select sum(items) from my_table where ...
```

the result I am getting back (ruby) is of type `BigDecimal`. Is there any SQL magic I can apply to get back an `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast(sum(items) as binary) ...
```

worked well for me

Comment: Why would casting as `BINARY` be better than, say `INT`?

Comment: `select cast(sum(items) as int) from my_table ...`
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'int) from my_table' at line 1

Comment: You need to use "AS SIGNED" as per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/323307/324900

Answer (score 2):

You get BigDecimal results when performing operations like this on `NUMERIC` columns. What you probably want is to either convert it in Ruby with a `collect` operation, or on the MySQL level by casting to an integer before returning it:

```
SELECT FLOOR(SUM(items)) FROM my_table WHERE ...
```